# Where do I place the connection string in an ASP.NET Core library project that has no startup file?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have asp.net core library project.

I want to add connection string to it. I don't have startup class in this. Where I need to place connection string and how to fetch it?

Comment: Don't add connection strings to Libraries!!! connection strings are always added tot he application's configuration, never to the library. That would be like saving your password in a class library, no one could change it and everyone who gets the library could read it ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In dotnet core you can manage configuration using json files, which is one in many ways to configure your application.

According to the [dotnet core configuration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration) you can simply do (copied from link reference)

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.IO;

// Add NuGet <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" and
// <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json"
// .NET Framework 4.x use the following path:
//.SetBasePath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\.."))

public class Program
{
    static public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
    public static void Main(string[] args = null)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        Console.WriteLine($"option1 = {Configuration["option1"]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"option2 = {Configuration["option2"]}");
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"option1 = {Configuration["subsection:suboption1"]}");
    }
}
```

Then in your `appsettings.json` file you can add:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    },
}
```

And access it in code using `Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingDatabase")`

I can recommend also reading the [dotnet core documentation regarding connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings)

EDIT: As the commentors mention on your post, don't add connection strings and config files to your library code - do this from your console application or the web application!

Additional forms of configuration for dotnet core includes [user secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets), [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) and perhaps XML files or other forms of storage, as pointed out in the comments

Comment: This is not completely true. The configuration system allows you to put settings in various places, e.g. JSON files, XML files, environment variables, user secrets..

Comment: @juunas you are absolutely right, thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the post to be clearer on this matter.